# How to debug auto-generated code?

Tags: c#, async-await, decompiler

I am trying to see what goes on in the IAsyncStateMachine at runtime ,and i desperately need to see what variables it has and what it calls.I know you can see the code with the ILSpy ...but i need to debug it.

Is there any  method?
I need to see what goes on inside the IAsyncStateMachine MoveNext method !

```
public sealed partial class MethodBuilder<T> : Errand.MethodBuilder {

            public static new MethodBuilder<T> Create() => new MethodBuilder<T>();

            public new void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine {
                this.myStateMachine = stateMachine;
                this.Task = new Task<T>(this);
                stateMachine.MoveNext(); //i have to see the properties of stateMachine and inside this method !!!!!
            }

            public new void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine machine) where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine {



            }
            public void SetResult(T result) {
                this.Task.isCompleted = true;
                this.Task.result = result;
            }
            public new void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) => base.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
            public new void SetException(Exception ex) => base.SetException(ex);
}
```

Comment: It is not obvious why you have trouble debugging the decompiled code.  Except perhaps for one reason I can think of, use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, untick "Just my code".

Comment: It is unticked and yet i can not step into the stateMachine.MoveNext() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN [How to: Debug .NET Framework Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx).

**To enable .NET Framework source debugging**

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, click the Debugging category.

   - In the General box, set Enable .NET Framework source stepping.
   - If you had Just My Code enabled, a warning dialog box tells you that
     Just My Code is now disabled. Click OK.
3. If you did not have a symbol cache location set, another warning
   dialog box tells you that a default symbol cache location is now
   set. Click OK.
4. Under the Debugging category, click Symbols.
5. If you want to change the symbols cache location:

   - Open the Debugging node in the box on the left.
   - Under the Debugging node, click Symbols.
   - Edit the location in Cache symbols from symbol servers to this
     directory or click Browse to choose a location.
6. If you want to download symbols immediately, click Load Symbols
   using above locations.

   This button is not available in design mode.

   If you do not choose to download symbols now, symbols will be
   downloaded automatically the next time that you start the debugging
   your program.
7. Click OK to close the Options dialog box.

Comment: Ok so i have followed the steps but i still can't enter the MoveNext method of the IAsyncStateMachine.I can see the call stack but i want to be able to jump inside the method.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian See complete steps in the link. Also, select the proper visual studio version which you are using. There might be different instructions per each. Make sure the `Just My Code` option is unticked in Tools > Options > Debugging > General.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use   debugger.launch
once the debugger launch visual studio will prompt for vs version selection

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        Console.WriteLine("crap");
    }
}
```